# Multi line tooltip with CStatusBar and always activated

Tags: mfc, tooltip, statusbar

I am using the CStatusBar control and here is an example of trying to set the tooltips:

```c
m_StatusBar.CreateEx(this, SBT_TOOLTIPS);
m_StatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators_oclm, paneCount); //We create the status bar

m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo(paneDate, ID_INDICATOR_DATE, SBPS_NORMAL, 200);
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo(paneProgressOrZoomFactor, ID_INDICATOR_ZOOM, SBPS_NORMAL, 200);
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo(panePageBreaks, ID_INDICATOR_PAGE_BREAK, SBPS_NORMAL, 200);
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo(paneSlipsPerPage, ID_INDICATOR_SLIPS_COUNT, SBPS_NORMAL, 10);
m_StatusBar.SetPaneInfo(paneForeignLanguageGroup, ID_INDICATOR_FOREIGN_LANGUAGE_GROUP, SBPS_NORMAL, 200);
m_StatusBar.GetStatusBarCtrl().SetTipText(paneSlipsPerPage, _T("Line 1\r\nLine2"));
```

When I display the tooltip:

[image: Tip]

As you can see, it has not shown two lines:

> Line 1
>
> Line 2

I have researched it (example [here](http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/23a66d9a3b31193e.htm)) but to no avail.

## Update

Using slightly different code, sticking with just one line for the tip I now have:

[image: Tip 2]

You can see why I prefer multiline. In addition, I really want the pane text to read "Calendar to use" and the tip to have the information. But the tips only show if all the text is not visible. So I also need to make it always activated if possible.

## Update

I still can't get multiline but I have come up with a workaround for some of it:

1. Get the width for "Calendars to Use"
2. Set the pane width to that value
3. Update the pane text as "Calendars to Use          " (causes the tooltip notification)
4. Set the tip text

The icon on the cake is getting the multi line support

I tried:

```
static CToolTipCtrl* pToolTip = NULL;
CToolTipCtrl* ptt = AfxGetModuleState()->m_thread.GetDataNA()->m_pToolTip;
if (ptt != pToolTip) {
    // new tooltip
    ptt->SetMaxTipWidth(400);
    pToolTip = ptt;
}
```

But the code never gets called.

## Update

I have raised this as a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/488694/cstatusbarcontrol-and-multiline-tip-text.html) with Microsoft.